# Como coletar trechos de um texto com o objeto PageObject da biblioteca PyPDF2?

Tags: python, string, pdf, objetos

Vou **retirar um trecho de texto** de um **PDF** com a biblioteca `PyPDF2` em **Python**. Preciso **encontrar** a palavra "lc" dentro do PDF e extraí-la: a palavra "**lc**", que significa *locação*, vem **acompanhada de um número** (*número do pedido*) que vai *variar de documento para documento*.

A solução que havia imaginado seria coletar o termo "lc" + os próximos 5 caracteres. Não sei como fazê-lo como puder perceber pelos meus testes (vide código abaixo) - estou me iniciando em programação e talvez não saiba algo crucial ou não esteja enxergando algo.

**A pergunta é**: como posso coletar o trecho dentro do objeto `PageObject` da `PyPDF2`? Levando em conta que preciso coletar também os 5 caracteres seguintes ao termo pesquisado pois eles variam de documento para documento, e são desconhecidos.

```
import PyPDF2

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(r'C:\Users\1\Desktop\Escaneados\2.pdf'
    , 'rb')
p = reader.getPage(0)
text = p.extractText() 
search_word = "lc"

print (text[27:35])
```

Comment: Este PDF foi gerado, _aparentemente_, por meio de digitalização de um documento físico. Digitalizações sempre geram uma "foto" do documento digitalizado. Se utilizar um programa de OCR, ele transforma partes da imagem com texto em texto puro (caracteres) - mas pode haver falhas em algumas seções. **Pergunta**: ele passou por algum software OCR para transformar a "foto" do documento em texto puro? Veja: se ele não for um documento com texto puro e sim foto, não vai funcionar. Se a parte da foto que contém a imagem do texto de interesse não foi transformada em texto puro, não vai funcionar.

Comment: Bom dia José. o PDF foi foi gerado por uma multifuncional que está configurada para gerar arquivos pesquisáveis por meio de OCR.  A correção que você propôs é exatamente o ponto que está me prendendo aqui. Preciso extrair os números seguintes ao "lc" para poder salvar esses PDFs com o numero do pedido para localização. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pegue a posição do `lc` no texto:

```
pos = text.find('lc')
```

Em seguida use essa variável na hora de obter a fatia que quer:

```
print(text[pos:pos+10])
```

Uma outra opção é usar expressões regulares:

```
import re
m = re.search(r'lc\s+(\d+)', text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
else:
    print('not found')
```

Comment: As duas soluções funcionaram muito bem. Obrigado. Vou aprender mais sobre as expressões regulares para aplicar em outra parte do código.